# how to update different records in a field all over the products in odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, odoo

I want to update computed field records but it writes self record in all fields when I use write method.

the name field in product, template is non stored. now because of our business needs so I can't search it.

I make another stored field to move name records into it. so I can looking for instead of name.

I make a button to update data in that field from name field. but when I press the button it updates with self name not name of each product.

```
class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
def button_name(self):
    for rec in self:
        name=self.name
        rec.search([]).write({'nameseacrh': self.name})



name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=False ,compute=compute_amount ,search=pro_search)

nameseacrh = fields.Char(string="", required=False,store=True, compute=compute_search )
```

button XML

```
<button name="button_name" type="object" string="name" class="oe_highlight" groups="base.group_system"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do but here are already a few remarks:

```
@api.multi
def button_name(self):
    for rec in self:
        name=self.name  # remark 1
        rec.search([]).write({'nameseacrh': self.name})  # remark 2 and 3
```

1) You never use this variable

2) `rec.search([])` is the same as `self.env['product.template'].search([])`: It takes all the product templates in the db. You probably didn't want to do that... Then you write your values on all the records.

3) you use `self.name` instead of `rec.name`. The first one will work only if `self` is a recordset of one element, which will not be the case most of the time in an `@api.multi`

4) I don't get why you would need to make a new field that does what you had before. You shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: i added this field to copy name recode which non store to new stored one so i can search for 
beacuse the first one is non store because of our business needs

Comment: It still doens't make sense. Stored here or stored there doesn't impact your business needs.